# Facebook Plug-in Facepile Issue

Tags: javascript, facebook, api, facebook-social-plugins, facepile

I'm having trouble with understanding the basics of the Facepile plug-in for Facebook developers. I've successfully got Facepile up and running and displaying a picture of someone who 'likes' the page, as long as they're a friend.

That's all good. But there's another feature of Facepile that I just can't get working. And that's to simply display how many people have liked the page. On the Facepile developers page it says:

*If some users have liked your page, but none of the viewing users friends have liked it, the plugin will display the total number of users who have liked your page.*

However, this simply just doesn't show up for me. Is there something I might be missing? Here's my code as it appears:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>

  <script>(function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=00000000";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

  <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js
  #appId=0000000000000&amp;xfbml=1"></script>

  <div class="fb-like" data-href="http://myurl" data-send="false" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true"></div>

  <div class="fb-facepile" data-href="http://myurl" data-action="watch" data-max-rows="1" data-width="300"></div>
```

Bare in mind that I replaced the App ID and URL with dummies. An insights you might have will be hugely appreciated!

Comment: I think I understand your question now. It wasn't very clear when I first read it. You're asking why the second case isn't working for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update: After reading your question carefully, I'd recommend you to try the IFRAME version once to see if that works for you.**

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/facepile.php?href={SITE_URL}&amp;size=small&amp;width=292&amp;max_rows=1" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:292px;"></iframe>
```

**Old Answer:**

You don't need facepile, assuming "like count" is the only thing you need. Simply use Open Graph for it.

**Open Graph:**

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{PAGE_ID}
```

eg. https://graph.facebook.com/314467614927

**Returns:**

```
{
   "id": "314467614927",
   "name": "Angry Birds",
   "picture": "http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-snc4/276791_314467614927_795266395_s.jpg",
   "link": "http://www.facebook.com/angrybirds",
   "likes": 20292918,
    ...
}
```

Now retrieve the like count from the JSON, and populate it wherever you wish to display it using JS.